# I want it to detect the duplicate comment and give a warning on the same page

Tags: php, forms

When a user rewrites a comment, they are redirected to wp-comments-post.php and sees a warning.

I want it to stay on the same page and see the warning. How can I do that?

With the comment_duplicate_message(filter function), I can decide what to write. but the main thing is to show the warning.

Comment: This will need to be done in javascript to do that, however I don't see a way to make this work once comments overflows to a second page of comments

Comment: Actually I did this for name, email and comment. I can get alerts on the same page with javascript but I couldn't do this for duplicate comment.

Comment: If you can retrieve the comment body couldn't you loop through them and compare them against the input box before submit?

Comment: Actually I'm trying something similar but mostly i'm trying something via dupe_id.

I need a basic knowledge. I don't know exactly what to use. If someone can propose a function I can use, I can improve it.